# Calculating resistance with just voltage and an earlier current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I would like to calculate the resistance in a resistor in a circuit with a $9V$ battery. I have no ammeter; only a potentiometer. I do know, however, that the $9V$ when hooked up from terminal to terminal with just the wires induces a certain current $I^*$ (So $\frac{9V}{I^*} = R_{wire}$).

Having connected the resistor (of unknown resistance), I find the potential across its ends to be $V_r$. I want to find the resistance of this resistor. How do I do so, if it possible? Remember that I cannot measure any current here.
Can I take $\frac{V_r}{I^*}$?

Comment: I suggest that you consider the wire and the resistor as a potential divider.

Comment: In your first equation you are ignoring the internal resistance of the battery which exists for all real batteries.

Comment: "I do know, however, that the $9V$ when hooked up from terminal to terminal with just the wires induces a certain current $I^*$ (So $\frac{9V}{I^*} = R_{wire}$)." How do you know the current when you say later you have no way of measuring the current. Please clarify.

Comment: @BobD Aravind knows that the current value *exists*

Comment: You can create a voltage divider using a known resistance and an unknown resistance. You can then use the voltage to calculate the unknown resistance. (Basically you are calculating the current by using the voltage across the known resistance)

Comment: @BobD assume I was told by someone else (who had an ammeter) that it was so; take the I* as a given.

Comment: @user253751 So I hook up a resistor of a known resistance (say $9\Omega$) and measure the voltage across *that* (say $x$): then the current in the circuit is $x/9ohm$. So the unknown resistance is $V_r * 9\Omega / x$. Is it so?

Comment: @AravindSuresh Yes. You connect those two resistors (the known one and the unknown one) in series. When they're in series, the current has to be the same, even if you don't know what it is.